The Python Proxy Server not functioning
I have the below code written in Python for a proxy server (which should be able to cache web pages. It is a very simple proxy server which only understands simple GET-requests, but is able to handle all kinds of objects–not just HTML pages, but also images), but when I try to run it it doesnt do anything. I have activated the proxy settings on windows. Here is the code below:
enter image description here

`From socket import *
import sys
if len(sys.argv) <= 1: print ('Usage :"python ProxyServer.py server_ip"\n[server_ip : It is the IP Address OfProxy Server')
sys.exit(2)

# Create a server socket, bind it to a port and start listening 
tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Fill in start.
tcpSerSock.bind((sys.argv[1], 8888))
tcpSerSock.listen(5)
# Fill in end.

while 1:
  # Strat receiving data from the client
  print( 'Ready to serve...')
  tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
  print ('Received a connection from:', addr )
  message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode() # Fill in start.
  print(message)               # Fill in end. 

  # Extract the filename from the given message print message.split()[1]
  filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
  print(filename)
  fileExist = "false"
  filetouse = "/" + filename

  print (filetouse)
  try:
    # Check wether the file exist in the cache
    f = open(filetouse[1:], "r")
    outputdata = f.readlines()
    fileExist = "true"

    # ProxyServer finds a cache hit and generates a response message     
    tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n") 
    tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n")
    # Fill in start.
    for line in outputdata:
        tcpCliSock.send(line.encode())
    #f.close()
    # Fill in end.
    print ('Read from cache')
  # Error handling for file not found in cache
  except IOError:
      if fileExist == "false":
        # Create a socket on the proxyserver
        c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)# Fill in start. # Fill in end. 
        hostn = filename.replace("www.","",1)
        print (hostn)
        try:
            # Connect to the socket to port 80
            # Fill in start.
            c.connect((hostn, 80))
            # Fill in end.

            # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80 for the file requested by the client
            fileobj = c.makefile('r', 0)
            fileobj.write("GET "+"http://" + filename + " HTTP/1.0\n\n")

            # Read the response into buffer
            # Fill in start.
            buffer = fileobj.read()
            # Fill in end.

            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file. 
            # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket and the corresponding file in the cache
            tmpFile = open("./" + filename,"wb")
            # Fill in start.
            tmpFile.write(buffer)
            tmpFile.close()
            tcpCliSock.send(buffer.encode())
            # Fill in end.
        except:
                print ("Illegal request")
else:
    # HTTP response message for file not found 
    # Fill in start.
    tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n".encode())
    tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type:text/html\r\n".encode())
    tcpCliSock.send("\r\n".encode())
    tcpCliSock.send("<html><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n".encode())
    # Fill in end.
    # Close the client and the server sockets
    tcpCliSock.close()
# Fill in start.
tcpSerSock.close()
# Fill in end’


Any help would be much appreciated
I tried the code on my computer, using cmd and i attached a
picture of the result. It doesnt seem to contiue


The very first token of the code shown here will give an error: From is distinct from from. Please [edit] your question and show us your exact code, or an accurate [mre]. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Even under the assumption that the From is a copy paste error, the sys.exit(2) on the fourth line is currently unconditional, which would always exit the program.

don't put code in one line with if. Put it in next line with indentation. Now you have wrong indentation - exit should be inside if but you have it outside if.

I don't know if I should even write answer because it so stupid mistake.
You have to put exit inside if - so you have to put print() and exit with indentations
if len(sys.argv) <= 1: 
    print ('Usage :"python ProxyServer.py server_ip"\n[server_ip : It is the IP Address OfProxy Server')
    sys.exit(2)


I didn't test rest of code. I only connected using server IP as web page address in browser and program gets connection - but I didn't test it as real proxy in browser.
